# More than one Windows Hello-compatible fingerprint readers?

Tags: fingerprint, windows-hello

I have a working fingerprint reader in Windows Hello.

If I wish to add another Windows Hello capable fingerprint reader to Windows, will both work?

Or do I definitely have to disable one to use the other?

Comment: So this question is about connecting multiple fingerprint readers, correct?

Comment: Yes it is about connecting multiple fingerprint **readers**, and using all of them (not at the same time), preferrably without disabling any of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Windows Hello fingerprint on the fingerprint reader. That works just fine.

You can only have one working fingerprint reader. Windows will assume the working fingerprint reader to pass the Hello reading to Windows.

So you  very likely need to enable only the one reader you are using.

I have done some searching and there is no suggestion anywhere I have seen that you can have more than one reader. So just stick with one and disable the other.

The purpose for one fingerprint reader with multiple fingerprints is so that if one fingerprint does not work, you can try the other and it might work.

Comment: You use the word “fingerprint” but never state “fingerprint reader.” Is that what you mean? That Windows allows multiple fingerprint readers? Meaning when you say, “You do not have to disable either. You can use both.” Do you mean that two readers can be used?

Comment: Windows allows multiple fingerprints on the fingerprint reader. I did clarify for everyone reading.

Comment: The question is about multiple fingerprint readers. So when you state, You do not have to disable either. You can use both.” Do you mean that two readers can be used?

Comment: I have further clarified.

Comment: So I can have 2 readers, but I have to disable *readerA* if I wish *readerB* work?

Comment: I have not seen 2 readers on numerous machines, but I would disable one so the the one you are using works properly

Comment: I did some searching and there is no suggestion you can have more than one reader so just stick with one.

Comment: "No suggestion you can have more than one": in spite of there is no suggestion: **can** windows handle more than one or **no**? This question only 2 kind of people can answer: a.) Has deep knowledge in Windows drivers (especially in Hello compatible ones), or b.) Has two readers and already tried using them. Anything else are just assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested 2 readers, and they can work perfectly.

You however need to register your fingers on both of them to work (ie. if you've registered your index finger on ReaderA, it will not work with ReaderB. You'll have to register it with ReaderB too to make it work with it).

Other than that, no limitations: you can login with using either one without disabling the other.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I had to register another finger, so it seems, that each fingerprint is mapped to a specific fingerprint device

Comment: It might depend on devices. For me it's still working perfectly with same finger.